# Sending the form without the submit button

Tags: html, forms, send

I making pagination and I want insert in text field in form number a page and form will send when user press enter or will move the cursor out of the text field.

```
<form method="GET" action="/site">
<input type="text" name="page" />
</form>
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with pure Javascipt. Here is a rough pseudo-code to start you off inside IIFE:

```js
<form method="GET" action="/site">
    <input type="text" name="page" id="yourInput" />
</form>

<script>
(function() {
    var el = document.getElementById('yourInput'); //Get your input by ID
    el.onblur = function() { // when focus lost...
        this.form.submit(); // submit the form
    }
})();
</script>
```

Comment: I receive notice from console - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onblur' of null

Comment: @polyman That means that there is no element with ID `yourInput`, or whatever you named it.